# RunKit samples for react native not working

Tags: reactjs, native, runkit

Does anyone know why the samples (contacts) in RunKit are not working?
I tried various samples around contacts and all have syntax error.
https://runkit.com/npm/react-native-paged-contacts
https://runkit.com/npm/react-native-contacts-android

Thanks,